# Python - NameError 'name_q' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

So I have been playing around with coding and so on and I just do like really random stuff, right now im doing so I just do random names inbuilt with my script basically Barry can turn to Henry or B.a.r.r.y. Nothing special.

The issue though is that whenever I try to print out or use name_q.get() in another method, it gives me a error saying NameError. What did go wrong?

```
def main():
    names = name_q.get()
    log(names)
    exit()

def test():

    name_q = Queue()
    user_input = int(input('How many random names you wanna make out of Barry? [NUMBERS] \n'))
    Names= "barry"
    generator = NamesGenerator(Names).generate()
    for i in range(0, user_input):
        name_q.put(generator[i])
    main()
```

Comment: This code can't run. Even if it ran due to your syntax error forgetting a `'` char, if wouldn't do much as you only have 2 functions, and none is called.

Comment: Short answer: variables created in one function are generally not accessible in any other function.

Comment: I dont understand right now, Could you please explain to me since im a rookie around these things :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `name_q` is local to the function `test`. It doesn't exist in function `main`.

You have to give it as a parameter:

```
def main(name_q):
    names = name_q.get()
    log(names)

def test():
    name_q = Queue()
    user_input = int(input('How many random names you wanna make out of Barry? [NUMBERS] \n'))
    names= "barry"
    generator = NamesGenerator(names).generate()
    for i in range(0, user_input):
        name_q.put(generator[i])
    main(name_q)
```

---

*NB: this has nothing to do with your problem but please put capital letters only at the beginning of class names, not to any variable. If you don't, this will lead to misunderstanding when people read your code.*

*Moreover, Python code should be written with a maximum of 79 columns, as indicated in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).*

Comment: Oh this actually help me! thanks alot, really apprecaite it!